# How to edit a file in a Pull Request?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps, and we would like to enable the feature to edit a file in a Pull Request. This is what we see in the file explorer of the Pull Request:

[image: Edit disabled]

As you can see, the `Edit` option is disabled.

Where is the option to enable this policy?

Thank you!

Comment: This is just a guess, but is your user part of the contributors group in repository?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops

Comment: You need to edit your code in your PR source branch and commit the changes in to update the PR, and If you are a reviewer of the pull request, you can a add comments to the [review codes changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pullrequest?view=azure-devops) .

Answer (score 2):

The premise of your question is flawed. You can't enable that feature because *it doesn't exist*. That's **not** the file explorer for a pull request. That's the file explorer for a specific commit.

You probably went to a file in the "File" view of the pull request, clicked the ellipsis, and chose "view in file explorer". That's a view of the file in the latest commit. It's not intended to be editable.

Comment: Daniel, thank you very much for your answer! What does the `Edit` button mean then? Do you know how to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: @Leandro The edit button is for when you're looking at a file in the Repos view. You can't edit a file in a pull request. You can edit a file in a branch that is under review for merging, same as you'd edit any file.

Comment: I found it very useful you mentioning that you can only edit files from the `Branches` section. If you add it to your comment, I will mark it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

I only just found out that there is a way to edit code directly in a PR:

1. Go to the Files tab in the PR and find the part you want to edit
2. Select (highlight) the part you want to edit and click the comment icon (speech bubble)
3. Under the comment field select "insert a suggestion" (lightbulb icon)
4. In the comment editor, edit the code to what you want it to be, and save your comment
5. When viewing the comment just made, click "Apply change", then "Commit all changes", then fill in the form that pops up